# Alter table and drop constraint from h2 database using nested query or variable

Tags: sql, h2

I am trying to drop a constraint on table `LEARNING` and column `PERSON_ID` from an in memory h2 database that I use for spring boot testing.

I tried using a variable:

```
SET @cnstrnt=select CONSTRAINT_NAME from information_schema.constraints where table_name='LEARNING' and column_list='PERSON_ID';
alter table learning drop constraint @cnstrnt;
```

and using a nested query:

```
alter table learning drop constraint (select CONSTRAINT_NAME from information_schema.constraints where table_name='LEARNING' and column_list='PERSON_ID');
```

Both complain about `expected IDENTIFIER`.

I can however remove the constraint when I first execute the select where I find the `CONSTRAINT_NAME` and use copy this value in the `drop constraint` query. I want to do this without manual intervention.

Can you tell me why I fail to drop the constraint with the queries above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a string **value** as an **identifier**. Actually you can't replace an identifier with anything else, you need to know its name.

You can execute the inner query from Java code and generate the second command. There is no way to do in with SQL only in H2 1.4.199 and older versions, the upcoming 1.4.200 will have an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SQL string'` command for this purpose.

Of course, you can define a Java function directly in the SQL code and call it, if you really need to perform this task from some SQL script, but such solution will be overcomplicated.

Comment: Okay. I am migrating the database using Flyway and that's why I'd have like to do it in the migration scripts for h2. For a `mysql` database it will be possible using SQL only?

Comment: In MySQL you can use the dynamic SQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html, in H2 you need to embed Java code in your SQL file: https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_alias, dynamic SQL in MySQL will be simpler.